# How to boil maize(Indian corn)?

Tags: corn

I bought some maize(also known as Indian corn or flint corn). Do you boil it just like regular corn on the cob? If so, how long do you boil the corn?

Answer (score 2):

Flint corn has a very hard outer layer to it.  If it's mature and dried, you may need to simmer it for some time, then attempt to work the hull off.

There was an episode of 'My Grandmother's Ravioli', where they made an [indian corn soup](http://www.cookingchanneltv.com/recipes/george-martins-indian-corn-soup.html).  The recipe posted online calls for [nixtamalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixtamalization):

> Remove the corn kernels from each ear by using your thumb to push kernels up and off the cob.
>   Heat a large cast-iron pot over medium-high heat. Add the kernels, the hardwood ash and water to cover by 4 inches. Bring to a boil and cook for 1 hour, or until most of the hulls have fallen off the kernels. Strain through a drying screen or colander. Rinse the corn with fresh water until all the ash is removed and the water runs clear.

Comment: I give the really hard stuff, dent corn, a 90 minute boil with the lime to get it tender. Finishing the nixtamalization requires a further overnight soak. Rinsed and cleaned up, stuff is pretty tasty after that.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Seasoned Advice! Indian corn can be boiled like regular corn on the cob *if* you get it while it is young and still tender and juicy. Regarding cooking time, like any other corn it will depend on the size of the ears.